# Don't add the css to the link with the active class

Tags: html, css

is there a way in CSS that you wouldn't add the css to the li?

So here's my example html

```html
<li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link active" id="components-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#components" role="tab" aria-controls="components" aria-selected="true">
        <i class="la la-lg la-cube"></i> <div><small>Components</small></div>
    </a>
</li>
<li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link" id="blocks-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#blocks" role="tab" aria-controls="blocks" aria-selected="false">
        <i class="la la-lg la-image"></i> <div><small>Templates</small></div>
    </a>
</li>
```

So in the links in my `li` I only want to add the css to the `nav-link` that does not have the `active` class.

How can I do this in pure css?

Thank you!

Comment: A common way to work around this is to apply the style to all of the items and then overwrite it for the `active` class (Reverting it back to the original style)

Answer (score 0):

Remove active class from a tag and give it to `<li>` and give all `CSS` properties in `<li>` tag and make a tag `display:block;` and don't give padding into `<li>` but give it to `<a>`.

```css
li{
   background-color:#fff;
}
li a{
   color:#000;
}
li.active {
  background-color: #000;
}

li.active a {
  color: #fff;
  padding: 15px;
}
```

```html
<li class="nav-item active">
  <a class="nav-link" id="components-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#components" role="tab" aria-controls="components" aria-selected="true">
    <i class="la la-lg la-cube"></i>
    <div><small>Components</small></div>
  </a>
</li>
<li class="nav-item">
  <a class="nav-link" id="blocks-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#blocks" role="tab" aria-controls="blocks" aria-selected="false">
    <i class="la la-lg la-image"></i>
    <div><small>Templates</small></div>
  </a>
</li>
```

Answer (score -1):

Use the css selector `:not()`. This styles every element with `nav-link` class except the one with `active` class

```
.nav-item .nav-link:not(.active){
/* your styles */
}
```

```css
.nav-item .nav-link:not(.active){
color: red;
}
```

```html
<li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link active" id="components-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#components" role="tab" aria-controls="components" aria-selected="true">
        <i class="la la-lg la-cube"></i> <div><small>Components</small></div>
    </a>
</li>
<li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link" id="blocks-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#blocks" role="tab" aria-controls="blocks" aria-selected="false">
        <i class="la la-lg la-image"></i> <div><small>Templates</small></div>
    </a>
</li>
```